# express.js Routing code positioning, does it matter?

Tags: node.js, express

Does positioning your route codes matter?

The reason I ask is because when I position my res.render("new") code
lower towards the page, the routing didn't work. If I put it higher on top, it routes accordingly. Example,

```
router.get("/tag/:id", controller.showBlog);
router.get("/:id/edit", controller.editBlog);

router.get("/new", function (req, res) {    
res.render("new")});
```

Code above.. Fail to route to new.ejs... no error, pushes me back to index.

```
router.get("/new", function (req, res) {
res.render("new")});

router.get("/tag/:id", controller.showBlog);
router.get("/:id/edit", controller.editBlog);
```

Code above.. Able to route to new.ejs

UPDATE solved.

Although sample code shown is not exactly as above,
it is indeed due to a get("/:id") route above the get("/new") that 
causes ("/:id") to be called before reaching ("/new"). 
In order words, positioning your Routes are important.

I also ran set DEBUG=express:* & node app.js

Here's the log for the working desired outcome.

[image: Correct Route]

Here' the log for the incorrect placement of my Routing code.

A Line item that show's something's not right.

[image: Incorrect Route]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these the only routes in your application? For the routes you have described, it shouldn't matter. But consider the following:

```
app.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
  // this will match all /a, /b .. including /new
  res.end('done!');
});

app.get('/new', function (req, res) {
  // this is never called
  res.end('done!!');
});
```

In the above scenario, `/new` handler will never be called.

Comment: You are absolutely right ! ... I had a get (' /:id') on top that catches /new first before going to my actual get('/new')

In other words, positioning of routes do matter.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to debug with just that code, but you may have luck using express's debug mode to see exactly why the strange behavior is occurring:

Launch the app using:

`DEBUG=express:* node index.js`

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. Apparently, the issue is indeed due to the positioning of routes. Regardless, your sharing of debugging express have been helpful. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap `showBlog` and `editBog` in anonymous functions. Also i'm not sure about the syntax `controller.showBlog` or `controller.showBlog()`

With anonymous function:

```
router.get("/tag/:id", (req,res)=>{controller.showBlog()});
router.get("/:id/edit",(req,res)=>{controller.editBlog()});

router.get("/new", function (req, res) {    
res.render("new")});
```