# Express.js main router working, but others routers on him not

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router, root

I have the problem on routers. My main route /weather working, but others routers on him don't.

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const weatherRoute = require('./back/routes/weatherRouter.js');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.disable('etag');
app.use('/weather', weatherRoute);
```

weatherRouter.js

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const wholeData = await WeatherInfo.find();
        res.json(wholeData);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err })
    }
});

router.get('/now', (req, res) => {
  res.send("ITS NOT WORKING");
});

module.exports = router;
```

the problem is that ****localhost:5000/weather**** working perfect, but when I want to use some other routers on that Route e.g. ****localhost:5000/weather/now**** that's not working 
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

UPDATED :

it works, when between those routers is no others routers.

e.g.

```
 router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
//working 
    }
    router.post('/:add', async (req, res) => {
//working
    }
    router.get('/now', async (req, res) => {
//doesnt work
    }
```

If I move /now above /add router it works perfect. Can someone explain why is this happening ?

Comment: it works for me. can you stop and start the server to check?

Comment: It works for me as well on express@4.17.1

Comment: updated my question. Like i showed my code here it works, but in my original code it doesn't, because between those routers there are more of them and then it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
The routers position is matter. [Reference to explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580721/express-js-routing-code-positioning-does-it-matter)
My last router didn't work, because another router already catched him.

```
app.get('/:add', function (req, res) {
  // this will match all /a, /b .. including /new
  res.end('done!');
});

app.get('/now', function (req, res) {
  // this is never called
  res.end('done!!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Define actual path in path section like**router.post('/weather/now', (re, res) => {
//Handel re
}

Comment: The problem was just about position.